# Algorithm exercise, object manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

i'm doing some exercise to improve my algorithm skills but i'm struggling with this one, the data array must be formatted to match expectedStructure and put inside newStructure. If someone can give me a hint on how to do this using ES6 syntax that would be awesome, thanks!

https://jsbin.com/jazatimumo/edit?js,console,output

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "style",
    buckets: [
      {
        count: 38243,
        ratio: 4.476200397255031,
        name: "romantic",
        md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00"
      },
      {
        count: 14414,
        ratio: 1.6871048956942187,
        name: "retro",
        md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "color",
    buckets: [
      {
        count: 26219,
        ratio: 8.1271048953942982,
        name: "blue",
        md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00",
        buckets: [
          {
            count: 11976,
            ratio: 3.1271048953942982,
            name: "lightblue",
            md5: "4457168314f0e9010d425f1d9db67937"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

let newStructure = [];

const expectedStructure = [
  {
    count: 38243,
    ratio: 4.476200397255031,
    name: "romantic",
    md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00",
    field: "style",
    label: "style = romantic"
  },
  {
    count: 14414,
    ratio: 1.6871048956942187,
    name: "retro",
    md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00",
    field: "style",
    label: "style = retro"
  },
  {
    count: 26219,
    ratio: 8.1271048953942982,
    name: "blue",
    md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00",
    field: "color",
    label: "color = blue"
  },
  {
    count: 11976,
    ratio: 3.1271048953942982,
    name: "lightblue",
    md5: "4457168314f0e9010d425f1d9db67937",
    field: "color",
    label: "color = lightblue"
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you sure the input is right? Specifically is the `color` set 2 levels deep or should it have been like the `style` one and 1 level deep?

Comment: yes the input is right, i've put the link to the original exercise which is on jsbin as its easier to test things

Comment: no its limited to two levels, same as on the input

Comment: It's the last color, 'lightblue' that prevents us from doing this recursive. If lightblue was also inside the colors bucket, or if lightblue would have the label "blue = lightblue", we could make this scale into infinity in one easy algorithm. As written, it takes a bit more work.

Comment: Yes it’s the last bucket that is two levels deep that’s making everything hard x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can use recursion and achieve this.
I have broken these into functions for code readibility.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "style",
    buckets: [
      {
        count: 38243,
        ratio: 4.476200397255031,
        name: "romantic",
        md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00"
      },
      {
        count: 14414,
        ratio: 1.6871048956942187,
        name: "retro",
        md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "color",
    buckets: [
      {
        count: 26219,
        ratio: 8.1271048953942982,
        name: "blue",
        md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00",
        buckets: [
          {
            count: 11976,
            ratio: 3.1271048953942982,
            name: "lightblue",
            md5: "4457168314f0e9010d425f1d9db67937"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

let newStructure = [];


const expectedStructure = [
  {
    count: 38243,
    ratio: 4.476200397255031,
    name: "romantic",
    md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00",
    field: "style",
    label: "style = romantic"
  },
  {
    count: 14414,
    ratio: 1.6871048956942187,
    name: "retro",
    md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00",
    field: "style",
    label: "style = retro"
  },
  {
    count: 26219,
    ratio: 8.1271048953942982,
    name: "blue",
    md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00",
    field: "color",
    label: "color = blue"
  },
  {
    count: 11976,
    ratio: 3.1271048953942982,
    name: "lightblue",
    md5: "4457168314f0e9010d425f1d9db67937",
    field: "color",
    label: "color = lightblue"
  }
]
// Step 3: Take out the needed values and push it into the newStructure
// You can remove the buckets from the object and spread the rest of the properties
// ES6 ;)
function addToStructure (field, v) {
  const { buckets, ...all } = v;
  let obj = {
    ...all,
    field,
    label: `${field} = ${v.name}`
  };

  newStructure.push(obj);
}

// Step 2: Start traversing the buckets to add the object to newStructure
//
// Also, check if there's a nested bucket then 
// recurse over it and call traverse again
function traverse (field, buckets) {
    buckets.forEach((v) => {
      addToStructure(field, v);
      v.buckets && traverse(field, v.buckets);
    });
}

// Step 1: Run a loop over the whole data
data.forEach((value) => {
  let field = value.name;
  traverse(field, value.buckets);
});

console.log('IS EQUAL TO EXPECTED STRUCTURE ? =', JSON.stringify(newStructure) === JSON.stringify(expectedStructure))
console.log(newStructure);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Cool! I’m a beginner so I need to test out things before I understand, so I will do that ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Davey I have updated the answer a bit using ES6 syntax to omit values.
You can check-out `step 3` in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure over `field` and use an iterative and recursive approach for infinite nested `buckets`.

```js
var data = [{ name: "style", buckets: [{ count: 38243, ratio: 4.476200397255031, name: "romantic", md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00" }, { count: 14414, ratio: 1.6871048956942187, name: "retro", md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00" }] }, { name: "color", buckets: [{ count: 26219, ratio: 8.1271048953942982, name: "blue", md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00", buckets: [{ count: 11976, ratio: 3.1271048953942982, name: "lightblue", md5: "4457168314f0e9010d425f1d9db67937" }] }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { name: field, buckets }) =>
        buckets.reduce(function iter(s, { count, ratio, name, md5, buckets = [] }) {
            s.push({ count, ratio, name, md5, field, label: [field, name].join(' = ') });
            return buckets.reduce(iter, s);
        }, r), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A bit shorter with rest parameters for objects. It may require a newer JS or [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/)

```js
var data = [{ name: "style", buckets: [{ count: 38243, ratio: 4.476200397255031, name: "romantic", md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00" }, { count: 14414, ratio: 1.6871048956942187, name: "retro", md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00" }] }, { name: "color", buckets: [{ count: 26219, ratio: 8.1271048953942982, name: "blue", md5: "257927a09632991b08877ef6d29bec00", buckets: [{ count: 11976, ratio: 3.1271048953942982, name: "lightblue", md5: "4457168314f0e9010d425f1d9db67937" }] }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { name: field, buckets }) =>
        buckets.reduce(function iter(s, { buckets = [], ...rest }) {
            s.push({ ...rest, field, label: [field, rest.name].join(' = ') });
            return buckets.reduce(iter, s);
        }, r), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ok I don’t understand everything of what you did but I will test it out, thanks a lot !!